# address of 'var' will always evaluate as 'true' in gcc 4.8 version

Tags: c, gcc

With gcc 4.8.3 version when i try to compile my code, i am facing below issue.

error: the address of 'x' will always evaluate as 'true' [-Werror=address]

```
        if (x) {
           ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

code:-

```
boolean x[MEM_WORD_WIDTH];

if (mm (temp)) {
   intro= etcorn (mmd, with, packing,x, eiP, message);
}
else{
  if (x) {
   //code
  }
}
```

'x' is marked as boolean.
When i ran this with earlier gcc version (4.1.x). I did not see any issue.

Comment: And do you really not understand what this warning is trying to tell you?

Comment: x is an array, which will always have a real address in its scope

Comment: @johnney are you asking `why it gives warning in gcc 4.8.3 and not in 4.1.x ??`

Comment: @ThiruShetty, yes. For earlier version i did not see any issue. Why?

Comment: Ask the question clearly. Your question that I see from comment is saying completely different thing than that one posted!

Comment: Sure, My apologies

Comment: @Johnney to understand why it give warning, you need to go the gcc version release (4.8) changes. Many feature as been added and improved.

Comment: There was always an issue. But seeing as 4.1 and 4.8 are quite far a part as far as compiler versions go (discounting major version numbers), it's not unlikely that diagnostics just got better.

Comment: @ThiruShetty, Yeah i have gone through all those in gcc poring 4.8.x version @ https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/porting_to.html and i have resolved the issues which are listed in that link while compiling my code with upgrading version (4.8)  . But, i am seeing some other issues like above which needs to take care.

Comment: if you wish to suppress this warning you can try the option `-Wno-address` but if your condition is based on value stored in boolean array, you need to change the code like `if(x[Index])`

Comment: @StoryTeller,@ThiruShetty do you have any links where we have common issues which we need to take care of while upgrading the compiler version.

Comment: @ Thiru Shetty , No i don't want to suppress the warnings :)  I want to fix the code to make it error/warning free.

Comment: @Johnney.: Again you are not sure what is your question?

Comment: @ThiruShetty, Sure I will fix it in my code instead of suppressing warnings. Thanks.

Comment: @Johnney You should understand that there's really no point in writing something like that, since it's equivalent to `if (true)` and the compiler is telling you that it is going to remove the test since the outcome is always true.  Why not makes things simpler for everyone and simply delete it from the source code?

Comment: @Tom Karzes,I am totally new to 'c' and trying to debug the old code when i see any new warnings with new gcc compiler.

Comment: That warning gets annoying when it's generated from code in a macro that might be passed a pointer rather than an array, and which has to check that the pointer is not null — except that when it is invoked with an array as the argument instead of a pointer, the check is point(er)less.  That's a situation I face at work. There ultimately isn't a good solution. The best approximation is a checking and a non-checking macro; the downside is that if someone calls the non-checking macro with what could be a null pointer, the code breaks. Humans being fallible, that's guaranteed to happen somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your X is not a Boolean but an array of Booleans.

So, the if does not check any Boolean value, but the address of that array.